# Visual Studio 2010 Keep Output Window Open on Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way in Visual Studio to keep the Output (Debug) window open when starting a debug session (Press F5)? Currently, it flips back to the last source file I was viewing which is mildly annoying. I've looked hard for a setting or an extension. It's likely sitting right under my nose but darn if I can find it.

Comment: After posting this I realized there's a better way to ask this question: VS has a "Show Output window when build starts". I want a "Show Output window when debug starts".

Comment: You can edit your post/title/tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>. That should wait until you press a key before closing the console output window.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not quite what I'm looking for. There's a setting in VS called "Show Output window when build starts". I want an option to "Show Output window when debugger starts"

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean. You might be able to dock the debug window pane with some other VS window that doesn't contain your source files.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm wildly misunderstanding your question, Visual Studio stores two sets of window positions, one for when you're developing and one for when you're running.  Once you are running, you can arrange the windows however you like and they should remain in that position on subsequent debugs.

For example, in my IDE, I have the Error List, Output, Find Results 1 and Pending Changes windows along the bottom when I'm developing.  When I launch the debugger, that changes to the Output, Locals, Watch 1, Find Results 1, Breakpoints, Call Stack, Immediate and Command Windows.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding. I think the difference is I run the output window as a tabbed window. I like the full height of the screen to view debug and trace messages.

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense.  And yes, I can see how that would be very annoying.  I'm using some different extensions that add in a new TabWell and allow tab pinning, but that suffers from this problem as well.  Would floating the Output Window work?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too!  After you press F5, focus the visual studio window and click Debug -> Windows -> Output

This will add the debug output screen to your debugging window set.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** open notepad.

**2:** Type the name of your saved c++ file which you had like to stay and type "pause". eg: suppose the name of the c++ file is hello_world then type:
hello_world.exe
pause\

**3:** save the file with .bat extension on ur desktop

**4:** Open the file that u saved on the desktop and run ur c++ program
now see the result!

Comment: Instead of using 'step 1:' in your answer, which flows together, use a numbered list by starting each line with 1. 2. ec.